# Using Reality Composer Project File in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground, reality-composer

To my knowledge, Reality Composer Projects files `.rcproject` are commonly placed in Xcode projects along with all other source files, then the project can simply be referred to by its name:

[image]

For example, `let boxAnchor = try! Prototyping.loadNameOfScene()` is all that's needed to load a scene from the `.rcproject` named "Prototyping".

In Swift Playgrounds, however, the `.rcproject` just seems to get ignored when placed inside the `resources` folder, and when placed inside the `sources` folder, causes iPad playground to throw a compile error. Running the playground on iPad is necessary since Xcode cannot run AR. Regardless of what happens, the same line `let boxAnchor = try! Prototyping.loadNameOfScene()` now throws an error because "Prototyping" is not identified.

Is there any way to use `.rcproject` inside a Swift Playground?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by downloading them as .reality files. If you do that then you can use in playgrounds with no problem:

```
let prototype = try! Entity.load(named: "Prototyping")
    let leftAnchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
    leftAnchor.addChild(prototype)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(leftAnchor)
```

You probably can't use .rcp files for playgrounds because they're not targets like apps.